# JavaScript Button.click() does not work in Firefox, works fine in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, javascript, firefox

I have an ASP.NET button on my page. When I click the button using JavaScript (`buttonId.click()`), Firefox seems to fire all `onclick` event handlers on the page. I would like to click only one button.

This scenario is working fine in Internet Explorer.

Please let me know of any workarounds for this.

Thanks

Comment: where is your code dude?

Comment: We need to see some code. What is buttonId? Did you already find the element and assign it to a buttonId variable?

Answer (score 0):

The simple workaround is:

1. Make a `div`, `height 100%` of the page, `width 100%` of the page.
2. This `div` is hidden.
3. Make a function `showDiv()` that shows your `div`.
4. On every action in your page you'll use a JavaScript function.
5. The last row of all JavaScript function is `showDiv()`.

Then after every click that calls a JavaScript function other clicks on this page are disabled.

Ps. Obviously the `div` need remains align to viewport (`top=0;left=0`).

Comment: I wouldn't call that "simple" and I doubt it will solve the OP's problem.